# Problema con LOAD DATA INFILE: Salto de Registros

Tags: mysql

Estoy migrando una base de datos de Sybase 15.5 a MySQL 5.7.

Al no tener ninguna herramienta apropiada estoy usando el `bcp` para extraer datos de Sybase y el `LOAD DATA INFILE` para cargarlos en MySQL.

Exportación desde Sybase:

```
bcp BBDD..TABLA out TABLA.bcp -A2048 -c -t '&^' -r ''\\r\\n'' -T 33554432
```

Poniendo como separador de campos `'&^'` y separador de fila `'\r\n'`.

Importación desde MySQL:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'TABLA.csv into table TABLA
    -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY '&^'
    -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

Pero solo me carga 1 registro. (*hay 200000 registros a migrar*)

El **modelo** del fichero `.bcp` con los datos a extraer es:

```
145431056412&^xxxx@fdlkj.COM&^27124&^FI&^ &^R&^000000000000&^ &^00333&^000&^9202&^00333000082770021452ACF&^002011724&^R&^ &^216029000445&^Feb  1 2016  8:09
:24:126AM&^<HTML>
<HEAD>
 <TITLE>Notificación MiFID</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY bgcolor="#c8c8c8" bottomMargin=0 leftMargin=0 topMargin=0 rightMargin=0 marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">
<table bgcolor="#808080" width="100%" height="100%" cellspadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td><table width=750 border=0 align=center cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 bgcolor="#ffffff">
      <tbody>
        <tr bgcolor="#808080">
          <td colspan=3 align="center" style="FONT: 500 11px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;COLOR: #ffffff">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
--aqui va el cuerpo del html, no lo pego todo porque es muy largo, y continuacion las lineas finales
</TR>
          </TBODY>
        </TABLE>
  </tr>
</table>
</BODY>
</HTML>
\r\n145431056414&^xxx@erweoi.COM ---->aqui empieza el segundo registro
```

A la hora de procesar el comando, solo carga el primer registro ignorando el resto.

He intentado poner como separador  `'\r\n'`, `'\n'`, `'~\r\n'` pero con ninguna de las formas ha funcionado.

Comment: solo añadir que el campo que falla es un campo que contiene HTML (he copiado todo el codigo en el comentario anterior pero no ha salido) y el tipo de datos es longtext

Comment: Es importante que copiaras, en una etiqueta `code` como son los primeros 2 o 3 registros del archivo, ya que por lo que parece tienes problemas cuando pasas al segundo registro separándolo con \r\n

Comment: el primer registro es:
145431056412&^xxxx@fdlkj.COM&^27124&^FI&^ &^R&^000000000000&^ &^00333&^000&^9202&^00333000082770021452ACF&^002011724&^R&^ &^216029000445&^Feb  1 2016  8:09
:24:126AM&^<HTML>--aqui va el code que puse en el primer comentario
aqui empieza el segundo registro :
\r\n145431056414&^xxxx@ereerer.COM&^27125&^FI&^ &^R&^000000000000&^ &^00333&^000&^9202&^00333000082770022058ACF&^002011725&^R&^ &^216029000447&^Feb  1 2016  8:09:24:150AM&^<HTML>

Comment: como se ve separo los campos con &^ y las filas con \r\n pero no entiendo porque no funciona lo de separar las filas ya que al caargar solo me carga el primer registro del fichero

Comment: Te fijate que en el comando `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'TABLA.csv'` te falta un **'** ?

Comment: si pero es solo el copy paste al añadirlo aquí, el comando es correcto.

Comment: Creo que no es un impedimento que puedas usar como salto de linea otro tipo de caracter y no \r\n, creo que ahi tienes el problema. Podrías exportar de Sybase utilizando de salto de linea por ejemplo `&#` e intentando importarlo desde MySQL asi?

Comment: Perfecto!! Ha sido el separador, con &# ha funcionado!
Gracias